# return rowMean and CIs from a matrix using boot

Tags: r, boot

Simple question. I have a matrix `foo` and I want to bootstrap the mean value of each row and its 95% CI using boot. I want the output to be a `data.frame` with `nrow(foo)` and three columns the mean, lower CI, and upper CI. Seems simple but the `boot` and `boot.ci` syntax is eluding me.

I imagine I use `apply` with `boot` but I'm not sure how to go further. Any help appreciated.

First try.

```
foo <- matrix(rnorm(1000),nrow=10)
getMean <- function(x,ind){
  mean(x[ind],na.rm = TRUE)
}

meanBoot <- apply(X = foo,MARGIN = 1, FUN = boot,
                   statistic = getMean,
                   R = 200)
```

Edit: typo

Answer (score 1):

We may do

```
library(boot)
out <- do.call(rbind, apply(foo, 1, FUN = function(x) 
      {
    x1 <- boot.ci(boot(x, statistic = getMean, R = 200))
    data.frame(mean = x1$t0, lowerCI = x1$normal[2], upperCI = x1$normal[3])
      }))
```

-output

```
> out
          mean     lowerCI    upperCI
1  -0.13716932 -0.32814349 0.05074657
2   0.14091601 -0.03785282 0.30007863
3   0.06313605 -0.16234730 0.27028525
4  -0.08422669 -0.25017647 0.07886253
5  -0.07288179 -0.27784123 0.13525142
6  -0.03636316 -0.20738203 0.13542197
7  -0.13201509 -0.30910041 0.04210289
8  -0.16965578 -0.34039042 0.04289176
9  -0.05509720 -0.26274593 0.14733604
10  0.10166934 -0.09162666 0.29662724
```